# Storing API-responses in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, api

I have a function `get_dish()` which makes an AJAX-request to my back-end to retrieve a `Dish`-object with the requested ID.

```
function get_dish(id) {
    let url = "/api/dishes/" + id;
    let r;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            r = response;
        }
    });

    return r;
}
```

The problem I had is that when `get_dish()` is called a lot my page would slow down because of all the HTTP-requests.

So I came up with the idea to cache the objects I request in `localStorage`. So when `get_dish()` is called, the returned `Dish`-object gets stored in `localStorage`. To achieve this I made the following caching-system:

```
// system to cache objects requested from API.
class ApiCache {
    constructor(dishes) {
        this.dishes = dishes;
    }
}

// intialize ApiCache
if (localStorage.getItem("apicache") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("apicache", JSON.stringify(new ApiCache([])));
}

function apicache_add_dish(dish) {
    let apicache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apicache"));

    if (apicache_get_dish(dish.id) != null) {
        return;
    }

    apicache.dishes.push(dish);
    localStorage.setItem("apicache", JSON.stringify(apicache));
}

function apicache_get_dish(id) {
    let apicache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apicache"));
    return apicache.dishes.find(dish => dish.id == id);
}
```

The updated `get_dish()` looks like this:

```
function get_dish(id) {
    if (apicache_get_dish(id) != null) {
        return apicache_get_dish(id);
    }

    let url = "/api/dishes/" + id;
    let r;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            r = response;

            if (apicache_get_dish(id) == null) {
                return apicache_add_dish(r);
            }
        }
    });

    return r;
}
```

This way, when the same dish is requested multiple times no HTTP-requests needs to be made, but it can just be retrieved from the cache instead. I'd but an expiration on the `localStorage` to belittle the chance of data inconsistency.

Is this a good idea? What are the pro's and cons? Can this be improved?

Comment: you can use cookies instead of local storage as they have expiration and you can set as per your requirements.

Comment: Another solution is using a state management like redux

Comment: Voting to close because this will lead to opinion-based answers, not factual answers. But I will comment that if you want to store for the same session but refetch on a new session, use sessionStorage, and if you only care about the current tab, there's no need for storage at all, you can use a state management library or a simple cache (similar to what you already have, but without the storage).

Comment: @Anis @ZanAnger What about just using `Cache-Control` in the HTTP-header?